# I am learning about pointers in C and am starting with a basic idea, but I keep getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning about pointers in C and am starting with a basic idea: using a pointer to go through and change an array. Then print that array. What mistakes am I making?

I was told you can go through an array by assigning it to a pointer variable, as I have done below:

```
int main(void){
  int i = 0;
  char entry[40], n, p;

  p = entry;

  printf("Enter a sentence: ");
  while ((n = getchar()) != '\n'){
    *(p + i) = n;
    i++;
  }
  *(p + i) = 0;

  printf("%s", p);

  return 0;
}
```

I've been experimenting with different ways of doing this for a bit now and could use some help. I keep receiving errors such as:

- assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
- invalid lvalue in assignment

Comment: `p = entry;` : `p` is a `char` but `entry` is an array.... probably not what you intended. Perhaps you meant for `p` to be a `char *`. I.e., `char entry[40], n, *p;`

Comment: Welp. That was a silly mistake I didn't catch. Thanks!

Comment: No problem; I'm glad you're assisted. I've voted to close this question for the "simple typographical error" reason.

Comment: @MoreFoam A good way to think about it is that a pointer is just a variable that holds a memory address to something else as its value. If you want to get what that something else is from the pointer, you dereference it with a `*` (e.g. `char n = 'A'; char *p = &n; printf ("\n address of n : %p\n value at n : %c\n\n", p, *p);` ) Will print something like `address of n : 0xbf8c344b`  `value at n : A`

Answer (score 1):

- > assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

  This refers to code `p = entry` where you try to assign a pointer (`entry`) to p which is of type char
- > invalid lvalue in assignment

  This refers to `*(p + i) = n` as `(p + i)` is a number (a char can be considered as an int for this case) and not a pointer, thus cannot be assigned.